# Temporarily changing the Apple account on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

### Why I'm asking

I am a developer. I'm a very recent newcomer to the world of iOS apps. And I only have a crappy old 2nd hand iPhone I bought specifically for this purpose. I have developed an app and it is misbehaving on several phones including my wife's phone. So, there is a great opportunity here for me to debug the problem on her phone. However, as I understand it, XCode will not allow me to connect her phone to my MacBook and inspect the app since it's logged in as another user.

### My Question

This may be a very stupid question (although I don't believe in stupid questions), can I log her out of her iPhone and log in with my Apple account. And if I do so, will horrific irreversible things happen with various settings and iCloud storage getting synced all over the place? After I'm done, I'd like to log her back in and we never speak of it again.

Comment: While jksoegaard addressed your issue, I would like to comment on changing accounts: better not to, unless absolutely necessary. To avoid data loss, some categories of data aren't cleared after signing out (such as photos). This data could be uploaded to your account, or to hers, after signing in.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is incorrect - there's no requirement that the phone needs to be logged in as the same user in order to use Xcode for debugging.